# Can I use the word "brevet" as a synonym for "patent"?

Tags: synonyms

I have to write a text where the word "patent", referring to various inventions published in Germany, UK, US and France, appears so often that I need synonyms for it in order to make the text less annoying. Can I use sometimes the word "brevet" instead? Are there other synonyms for "patent"?

I looked for the synonyms of "brevet" and [this is what I have found](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/brevet?s=t).

Comment: Please show that you have looked the word "brevet" in a dictionary.  What is the definition?

Comment: "Brevet" doesn't mean "patent" in English (though it does in French). I wasn't actually aware "brevet" was used in English at all until I researched it after reading your question.

Comment: Then, if exists, tell me a synonym for "patent" that works well.

Comment: I don't understand this question.  Your link doesn't show that brevet can be a synonym for patent.  It's not, it means "an officer with an honorific rank".  Anyway, "patent" is a technical legal term, and so is unlikely to have a synonym.  You need to rethink.  This is an XY problem,  you don't want a synonym, you want to use pronouns more skillfully.

Comment: @James K, The original text that I have to translate in English (with some modifications) uses the words "patent" and "brevet" as perfect synonyms. It is quite difficult to replace them with pronouns. If no serious synonym is available I will try to use, where it is possible: "document", "application", "license" but as long as I do not master the English language and the above mentioned words are not quite synonyms of patent I will never be sure whether I use them correctly or not.

Comment: my point is that "patent" is a legal term.  A patent might be written on a document but it is not an application nor a licence (in the legal sense). By the way, you are adding important information here.  "text I have to translate" Presumably from the French, This explains why you think that brevet might be a possible English word. My advice remains: use "patent" and "it"

Comment: What about the expression "certificate of invention" instead of "patent". Does it work?